# Why is "Whoever thought of that idea" a noun clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

> **Whoever thought of that idea** is a genius. [reference](http://www.k12reader.com/term/noun-clause/)
>
> whoever=anyone that [reference](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whoever)

I am confused by this clause and I think it should be a relative clause, because **"a person"** can be a **genius** instead of that clause **"Whoever thought of that idea"**.

**References**:

- [Fused relative constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Fused_relative_constructions)

Comment: It is a 'fused' relative construction where "whoever thought of that idea" is not noun clause but a descriptive noun phrase meaning "the person x satisfying the description 'x thought of that idea'". The single word "whoever" fuses (combines) the functions of antecedent and the relativized element in the relative clause, cf. "the person who thought of that idea".

Comment: It does function as the subject of the sentence and that is the function of a noun or pronoun.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your keyword "Fused relative constructions" :) So "Whoever thought of that idea" is a relative clause, right?

Comment: Haha, very good! No, it's a special construction, where "whoever thought of that idea" is a noun phrase where the head of the NP is also the relativized element in the relative clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *both* a relative clause *and* a noun clause.

The term *relative clause* describes the internal structure of the clause: it starts with a relative pronoun ("whoever") that plays a nounlike role inside that clause (subject of "thought of that idea").

The term *noun clause* describes the role the clause is playing in the larger sentence: it's the subject of "is a genius".

Relative clauses are usually adjective clauses ("the book **that we read** was very interesting"), but they also can be noun clauses (as in your example) or adverb clauses ("I talked to him, **as you suggested**").

Comment: Sorry, but that's not quite right. It's actually a noun phrase whose head is also the relative word in the relative clause, hence the term 'fused relative construction.

Comment: @BillJ "construction" is harder to understand than "clause" :( Can a fused relative construction be used as a relative clause?

Comment: @ruahk Thanks for your answer. It is reasonable :)

Comment: @BigShield Think of "whoever" as meaning "the person who", and then you'll see the noun phrase more clearly. The meaning is thus  comparable with that of the non-fused "the person who thought of that idea", which is clearly a noun phrase.